# Play 2.1 on Cloudbees with MySQL: No suitable driver found

Tags: playframework, cloudbees, playframework-2.1

I cannot get my application connect to database using Cloudbees.

I have in my configuration file:

```
# Database configuration
# ~~~~~ 
db.default.driver=${MYSQL_DRIVER}
db.default.url=${MYSQL_URL_DB}
db.default.user=${MYSQL_USERNAME_DB}
db.default.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD_DB}
```

In Cloudbees configuration, I have:

```
$ bees config:list -a me/my-app
Application Parameters:
  proxyBuffering=false
  MYSQL_URL_DB=jdbc:cloudbees://my-app
  MYSQL_USERNAME_DB=my-app
  MYSQL_PASSWORD_DB=dadadadada
  MYSQL_DRIVER=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
Runtime Parameters:
  java_version=1.7
```

Reading this, is seems that the driver is actually declared. The dependenci is in my Build.scala:

```
  val appDependencies = Seq(
    javaCore, 
    javaJdbc, 
    javaEbean,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.22"
  )
```

But on start, I get:

```
Caused by: 
    java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for 
    mysql://ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/my-app
```

I feel like I missed something reading the documentation but cannot find what...

Thanks,

**EDIT:** You can find my test application on [Github](https://github.com/adericbourg/proto-poll/). The bounty is for the one who'll manage deploying it on Cloudbees (and explaining how). Cloudbees configuration is not commited on Github.

Comment: For the full log, you may have a look here: https://gist.github.com/adericbourg/5189037

Comment: Did you try giving 5.1.18 version? Works for me.

Comment: I did. But it did not change anything...

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to try with mysql 5.1.18 connector. I have an application in CloudBees and works fine with that connector. Also try with a local database to see more easily where the problem is.

This is my **Build.scala**

```
val appDependencies = Seq(
    // Add your project dependencies here,
    javaCore,
    javaJdbc,
    javaEbean,
    "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.18"
  )

  val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies)
    .settings(cloudBeesSettings :_*)
    .settings(CloudBees.applicationId := Some("project_test"))
```

If this connector doesn't solve the problem, try the next configurations in **application.conf** (give especially attention to the username and password of the database in db.default.url.).

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="mysql://dbusername:dbpassword@localhost/DATABASE_NAME"
db.default.user=dbusername
db.default.password=dbpassword
```

Works fine for me.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I still get the same logs, having a ```502 Bad Gateway``` when accessing application :-(

The problem must be deeper than just a DB configuration...

Comment: db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/projwebwsdb" this is the url of my cloudbees database. If I was in your place, I would try working with the cloudbees database in your developer mode (not in cloudbees). Try to access to the database with a mysql client like SequelPro (for Mac OS) or MySQL Workbench.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that the Cloudbees application parameters (the ones you set with `bees config:set`) override the parameters you set in the left-hand side of your `conf/application.conf` file.

So in this case you don't have to set `MYSQL_URL_DB` as Cloudbees application parameter, but directly `db.default.url`

Just try:

```
bees config:set -a seo-machine -P db.default.url=jdbc:mysql://ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/my-app
```

and restart your app:

```
bees app:restart
```

Also don't forget to prefix the JDBC URL with `jdbc:` - only `mysql://ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/my-app` is not sufficient as URL

Answer (score -1):

Hey I just fixed this like right now. :)

You need to change the mysql_url to

MYSQL_URL_DB=jdbc:mysql://host:3306/my-app

Thing is that it default url is pointing to the cloudbees driver and since we are using mysql driver we need to change it to the mysql url.

Comment: so @smk when you say "host" you literally mean "host"? Or do you mean the amazon-ec3 address visible on the cloudbees database configuration page?

Comment: I updated my configuration to ```MYSQL_URL_DB=jdbc:mysql://ec2-23-21-211-172.compute-1.amazonaws.com:3306/foo``` but I get the same error. Weird...

Comment: Can u try restarting. And post logs if diff? Could u be seeing older logs?

Comment: Is that me or Cloudbees SDK is buggy? I get ```ERROR: Server.InternalError - For input string: "p"``` when I launch ```$ bees app:instance:restart -i <my instance>```...

Comment: I used the cloudbees play plugin https://github.com/CloudBees-community/sbt-cloudbees-play-plugin and play cloudbees-deploy